# Deta Space put method dumps data into one column

Tags: database

Deta Space put method not working. I tried implementing the put method specifying the key as "key" within a python dictionary. In the deta space database it just dumps all of the data under a auto-generated key.

implementing put method as per documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You literally have to specify the key as a separate required input.
Keys may or may not be pre-defined in your database.

```
username = "my_username"
input_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2) 
db.add_client(input_dict, key = username)
```